# Selenium WebDriver python bindings

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can't make python bindings for webdriver workable. [Here is](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings?redir=1) tutorial for installing.

> ```
> easy_install webdriver
> ```

Won't find webdriver package so I have to install it manually from sources. I've downloaded source from trunk, set **WEBDRIVER** and **PYTHONPATH** variables and installed webdriver:

```
   ~$ cd ~
   ~$ svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ selenium-read-only
   ~$ cd selenium-read-only
   ~# python setup.py install
   ~$ env |grep PYT
   ~$> PYTHONPATH=:/home/ockonal/selenium-read-only/../../../firefox/lib-src:/home/ockonal/selenium-read-only/..
   ~$ env |grep WEB
   ~$> WEBDRIVER=/home/ockonal/selenium-read-only
```

[Here is](http://dpaste.com/197879/) output of setup.py script.

Then I downloaded **RemoteDriverServer.jar** and ran it:

> ```
> java -jar RemoteDriverServer.jar 8888
> ```

Now I want to include webdriver module in python script:

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
```

> ImportError: No module named firefox.webdriver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

I'm guessing that selenium was installed to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/
```

In either the site-packages or dist-packages folder.

Since the link to your setup.py output is broken I can't see the results so I'm going to make some assumptions based on a 'normal' setup.py install

One of these folders should exist:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/firefox/
```

or

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/firefox/
```

This is the folder where the python library should exist based on the setup.py how the packages are defined in setup.py.

Now go back to the folder where you downloaded the source and navigate to.

```
./firefox/source/py/
```

Copy the all of the source files to whichever one of these two files exist.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/firefox/
```

or

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/firefox/
```

This is the equivalent to a 'manual install'. Although I'm not sure why you'd need to because the firefox parts of the package are clearly specified in the setup.py source.

```
...

'selenium.firefox': 'firefox/src/py',
...
```

If there is nothing for selenium under the site-packages or dist-packages folders the 'setup.py install' may not have installed correctly because it didn't have the required permissions.

Be sure to run 'setup.py install' with sudo if you haven't already. Since, root permissions are necessary to modify/add anything under '/usr'.

Answer (score 7):

the latest selenium (which includes webdriver) bindings should be [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org) installable:

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: Note that some systems have multiple versions of python and/or pip installed.  Make sure you use the right one.  Try installing under virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

You need copy `build/webdriver-extension.zip` to your python installation folder. Just copy the `build/webdriver-extension.zip` to `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/selenium-2.0_dev-py2.6.egg/selenium/firefox`.
It's an extension that you manually install.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

failed for me on Ubuntu 10.04

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I came to a different solution. Trying to run selenium in Python 3 which I installed via `homebrew`, and `selenium` installed via `pip3`. Got the same error of "ImportError: No module named 'selenium'". Checked my path using:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and found that where selenium was installed was indeed in this list (`/usr/local/lib/Python3.4/site-packages`).

However, I had downloaded the binary and so the folder named selenium was within the wrapper folder of `selenium-2.45`. Although perhaps not the greatest solution, I was able to get selenium running by copying the internal selenium folder to the same level as the `selenium-2.45` folder.

I don't think that this is a final solution, as it goes around the setup script, but for now, it seems to work just fine, and I am able to use the selenium module and its contents (so far).